# Which map to use in order to let users review places

Tags: api, maps, web-services, google-apps, openstreetmap

I'm creating an Ionic app, the user should be able to scroll to a place and review it, and he should be able also to check in and review the place. And also there should be gps directions.

So places, like restaurants, and everything should be already there, if not, the user should be able to add them by hand.

Multiple users should be able to review the same place, rate it and comment. If you don't use the app, you can't see the reviews.

My question is what Map to use? Considering using google maps, but not sure what part of the api gives that capability. There's also openstreetmaps but google maps is more popular, so there should in theory more locations in small countries. And there's mapbox etc.

What map api should I use, and what part of the api should I take a look at?

Bonus, if I could integrate my app with google maps, say you review this place using my app, the rating gets copied to google maps.

Comment: Bear in mind that you only get so many free hits per day on Google maps before you need to pay for a license.

Comment: Also - and this may not apply to you, or you may choose to ignore it & take your chances - but I found that Google's terms don't let you store it's data. I once wanted to get street addresses & store them in my own database. Google's terms prohibit this, so I had to request the data afresh every time, wasting bandwidth & incurring data transfer costs.

Comment: @Mawg storing data is essential in order to store reviews, unless i find another hack, what map did you end up using?

Comment: I used Google & requested the data anew every time I needed it :-(